# How does functional equality work in Scala?

Tags: scala

How is the equals function defined for a 'function' type:

```
val javaVersion = () => sys.props("java.version")

val anonfun0 = new Function0[String] {
  def apply(): String = sys.props("java.version")
}

assert(javaVersion() == anonfun0()) // This works!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works because you're comparing the result and not the functions. Remove the () and it should return false.

Comment: ah my oversight in guessing the intent!

Answer (score 2):

Your assertion is not testing the equality of the functions , but the value they return.

Note the difference between:

```
assert(javaVersion() == anonfun0()) // equality of return values
```

and:

```
assert(javaVersion == anonfun0) // equality of vals
```

Your assertion returns true because both functions return the result of sys.props("java.version").